# Align toolbar title in android

Tags: android, toolbar

This is my toolbar

[image]

I want change my title of toolbar like this:

[image]

I search about this but i cant find any result.

This is my toolbar code:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
                >
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your action_bar.xml

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

**EDIT:**
I would put them together inside a LinearLayout (horizontal) and then add the above command

Comment: It should be layout_marginBottom better.

Answer (score 0):

I think android is treating it as a normal view
So add this java code so that it can change the look of toolbar
Add in java

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers to understand your answer even better.